# Analytics platform of Forward proxy (squid) logs

Tags: proxy, analytics, squid, websense, bigdata

Are there any Open Source analytics or reporting tools which can work with forward proxy logs.

Primary goal is to build a analytics from forward proxy logs to get an insight on what are the employees looking for on web through Google search.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may push log using Logstash to Elastic and then to Kibana. Below can help you configure the same -

[Logstash, Elstic and Kibana setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[More can be found here](http://blog.webkid.io/visualize-datasets-with-elk/)